# NavLink exact prop not working for react-router-dom 6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am currently using

```
    "react-router": "^6.0.0-beta.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.0",
```

The problem with NavLink of react-router-dom that i am facing now is that the root path "/" is always active, other paths are of no problem and they are being active and inactive during toggle, its just the root path that is giving me trouble, i have searched and tried many solutions. but nothing worked.
Use "exact" and "exact={true}" both, but no success.

Used this:

```
<NavLink
          className="iconContainer"
          exact={true}
          to="/"
          activeClassName="isActive"
        >
          <span className="menu-title">Home</span>
        </NavLink>
```

and Also this:

```
<NavLink
          className="iconContainer"
          exact
          to="/"
          activeClassName="isActive"
        >
          <span className="menu-title">Home</span>
        </NavLink>
```

I have been stuck in this situation for past two days, and still no success in finding any solution.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Edit:
My routes

```
<Routes>
 
                <Route
                    exact
                    path="order/:orderId"
                    element={<OrderDetails />}
                ></Route>
                <Route
                    exact
                    path="orders"
                    element={<Orders />}
                ></Route>
                <Route
                    exact
                    path="/"
                    element={<Home />}
                ></Route>

                
      </Routes>
```

Comment: You need to pass another props: strict={true} or just strict
https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink/strict-bool

Comment: Can I see the route code, You might have missed the pah or something like that.

Comment: @Satyam Added routes, too. please check!

Comment: @Freestyle09 already used that, it was of no help.

Comment: Try using only `Link` instead of `NavLink`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**Exact** param will no longer work on NavLink components. In version 6 Beta they have included a new param called: `end`

With this simply approach you just need to pass `end` param for your `NavLink` component and `exact` to you `Route`

```
<NavLink end to="/">
      Go to Home
    </NavLink>
```

<strike>When you write `end="another-class-active"` you can change your active className which is `active` by default.</strike>

As @Greg Wozniak mentioned end is a boolean so you can't change active class name with this, instead of this you can pass a function to className:

```
className={({ isActive }) =>
    isActive ? 'activeClassName' : undefined
}
```

For more information read this:
https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#navlink

Working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-thompson-e7k8eb

<strike>**Note that this is still version Beta so we need to wait for some fixes and official releases**</strike>

Comment: adding ```exact strict``` to route and ```end``` to NavLink worked!

Comment: `end` is type `boolean`, you cannot provide a string value to it

Answer (score 3):

In 6.0.2 you can pass a function to className and that function gets a set of props. One of those props is "isActive". Here is how I solved it for the OP code:

```
<NavLink
    className={(props) => {
      return `${props.isActive ? 'isActive ' : ''}iconContainer`;
    }}
    end
    to="/"
  >
    <span className="menu-title">Home</span>
</NavLink>
```

Also note that the class "active" is automatically set by the
NavLink.

Also note the use of end: "If the end prop is used, it will ensure this component isn't matched as "active" when its descendant paths are matched. For example, to render a link that is only active at the website root and not any other URLs"

Answer (score -3):

However this how I did it, **you don't have to use exact in the case of `NavLink`** as said by the official docs, [LINK TO THE DOCS](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink)

```
   <NavLink to="/service" className='turner'>
      Services
   </NavLink>
```